# basic Windows 7 issue: difference between a Windows network drive and a Windows shared folder

Tags: windows

I would like to ask the following basic question. In Windows parlance, what is the
difference between a network drive and a shared folder? Examples welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In windows world is file structure starting with drive letter, typically C: as system disk. User profile directory path is typically (in Windows 7) C:\Users\username\.

You can select on your local disk some folder to be available to others in network and mark it as *Shared folder*. (RMB to folder > Properties > Sharing > Share ... > Select users to share with > Share) It's available then as Shared folder at network UNC path (in other Windows computers) as *\\computername\sharename*.

The Shared folder can be mounted in local system as Network drive, and so give the Shared folder a drive letter in your local system. (RMB Computer > Map network drive...  > Select Drive Letter, enter Shared folder UNC path \\computername\sharename > Finish). Then you can work with Shared folder locally as with files on the system disk C:, but at another drive letter (eg. Z:).

Comment: Thank you for your post. I found some information regarding the Uniform Naming Convention (UNC) here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Naming_Convention#Uniform_Naming_Convention

Answer (score 1):

The difference is if the share is mapped or not.

I can have a folder on a remote server \server\folder.

I can then share that folder to have a share.

If you the local client then maps that share, it is a mapped drive. This can be done with net use or through Windows Explorer.